# Maintain ImageButton URI and Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

in XML, I have image button without the src

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton1" android:layout_width="120px" android:layout_height="90px" android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

And I somewhere along..
I set either the URI or thumbnail using

```
((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3)).setImageURI(uri);
((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1)).setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Q1 Fixed!

Q2: When screen rotate, all my Image Buttons set with .setImageURI and .setImageBitmap is cleared. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: Try this ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3)).setImageURI(0);

A2:  [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Comment: About the saving application state, I can savedInstanceState.putString but I don't know how to put URI and Bitmaps.